# Scheduling individual setTimeout events using JQuery to occur in serial

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope to create a text transition animation using JQuery and have run into an issue of timing. I've looked around some other threads and have not been able to figure out the proper solution to what I am trying to accomplish. Here is the HTML I have:

```
<div id="t1">
    <span>T</span>
    <span>H</span>
    <span>I</span>
    <span>S</span>
</div>
<div id="t2">
    <span>T</span>
    <span>H</span>
    <span>A</span>
    <span>T</span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function showMessage(obj, up){
    if(dir){
        $(obj).children().each(function(i, el) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(el).animate({
                    'opacity': 1.0,
                    'top': '0px'
                }, 450);
            }, 500 + (i * 150));
        });
    } else {
        $(obj).children().each(function(i, el) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(el).animate({
                    'opacity': 0,
                    'top': '-30px'
                }, 450);
            }, 3000 + (i * 150));
        });
    }
}
showMessage("#t1", true);
showMessage("#t1", false);
showMessage("#t2", true);
showMessage("#t2", false);
```

Both `THIS` and `THAT` are being displayed at the same time. How can I make it so the second isn't displayed until the first has completely disappeared?

demo: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1oL0kkyv/3/)

Comment: lol, my question, exactly.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle to show what you are having problem?

Comment: of the top of my head, your problem is that you are going to run the four messages one right after the other so they will get loaded up in the settimeout right after each other.

Comment: `dir` is simply a boolean to define the direction. if it's `true` the text will display from the bottom, otherwise it will disappear upwards

Comment: @M.Bloom `dir` not appear defined within `showMessage` ?

Comment: `dir` is defined as a boolean as mentioned above. here is a [fidde](https://jsfiddle.net/1oL0kkyv/3/) to demonstrate what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you chain them?

```
showMessage("#t1", true, function(){
  showMessage("#t1", false, function(){
    showMessage("#t2", true, function(){
       showMessage("#t2", false, function(){});
    });
  });
});
```

and then include counters in your showMessage to check if all the spans have been displayed

```
    function showMessage(obj, up, callback){
    var counter = 1;
    var numberOfChildren = $(obj).children().size();
    if(up){
        $(obj).children().each(function(i, el) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(el).animate({
                    'opacity': 1.0,
                    'top': '0px'
                }, 450, function(){
                counter++;
                console.log(counter);
                if ( counter == numberOfChildren )
                {
                    callback();
                }
            });
            }, 500 + (i * 150));
        });
    } 
    else {
        $(obj).children().each(function(i, el) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(el).animate({
                    'opacity': 0,
                    'top': '-30px'
                }, 450, function(){
                counter++;
                console.log(counter);
                if ( counter == numberOfChildren )
                {
                    callback();
                }
            });
            }, 3000 + (i * 150));
        });
    }
}
$(function() {
   showMessage(".dev", true, function(){
    showMessage(".dev", false, function(){
      showMessage(".dev2", true, function(){
         showMessage(".dev2", false, function(){});
      });
    });
  });
});
```

updated `dir` to `up`.

Comment: @m-bloom can you try this and let me know if this has helped?

Comment: the callbacks do not work. it never seems to be running that nested function and iterating the counter

Comment: @M.Bloom is the 'dir' actualy 'up'? can you create a fiddle?

Comment: thanks! looks like the check for the callback was in the wrong spot. works great

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout is performed under vacuum. Anonymous function does not know about your external variables `i` and `el`

Comment: Not true; the anonymous function that is being passed to `setTimeout` does have access to `i` and `el` due to [closure](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/).

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting `.delay()` for `setTimeout` , calling second set of animations when `i` is equal to total `.length` of first set of animations within `.each()` called on `#t1` `.children()` : `span` elements

```js
function showMessage(obj, dir) {
  var first = obj[0], second = obj[1];
  $(first).children().each(function(i, el) {
    $(el).delay(500 + (i * 150)).animate({
      "opacity": 1.0,
      "top": "0px"
    }, 450, function() {
      // when all `first` : `#t1` `span` animations complete,
      // call `next` with `second`:`#t2` as parameter
      if (i === first.length) next(second)
    });
  });
  var next = function(elems) {
    $(elems).children().each(function(i, el) {
      $(el).delay(3000 + (i * 150)).animate({
        "opacity": 0,
        "top": "-30px"
      }, 450);
    });
  }
}
showMessage(["#t1", "#t2"]);
```

```css
#t1 span {
  opacity: 0;
  top: 30px;
}
#t2 span {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="t1">
  <span>T</span>
  <span>H</span>
  <span>I</span>
  <span>S</span>
</div>
<div id="t2">
  <span>T</span>
  <span>H</span>
  <span>A</span>
  <span>T</span>
</div>
```